# (RxAndroid / RxJava) Any way to check if the response from BehaviorSubject is the cached one?

Tags: android, caching, rx-android, rx-java2, behaviorsubject

I've been working with BehaviorSubjects with regards to presenters that listen in on the response of a subject without having to make the query themselves. I've been fascinated by the beauty of this type of subject.

However, the downside is... when a presenter is listening for the response of a new API call (say for instance, the response with the queried Product "A") and the BehaviorSubject automatically gives the cached response of an old request to it (e.g. gives the Presenter the response of the previously queried Product "B").

Any way to check if the response from BehaviorSubject is the cached one (so the presenter can use this checker before executing its necessary functions inside)?

Comment: If think you're not using the `Subject` under the right circumstances... Anyway, your Product surely have some kind of ID you can check. If the item emitted has a different ID than requested... then it's the cached one

Comment: I'm doing that already on my codes regarding the onNext()
but what if it's an error response? there's no way to tell (as far as I know) which Product the error response corresponds to.

I've already thought of inserting my query parameters into the emitted data so all presenters can check if the response is what they're listening to... but I was just checking in if you guys have some other ways to deal with this. Some way that perhaps deal with the BehaviorSubject cached response checking.

Btw, I've checked `distinct()` and `distinctUntilChanged()` but it's not the answer.

Comment: The errors emitted are just exceptions. You can catch any exception and wrap it around one of yours with extra information. Anyway, using the same subject for emitting different objects that seem not to have anything in common (talking about context)... I don't see it. There surely is some better approximation. Can you share the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: I see. This just pushes me to go insert some stuff into the response then. Thanks for your help, @Pelocho :)